# Can I copyright a homework assignement?

Tags: copyright

Suppose I have to write a paper for a class in college.  Am I allowed to copyright the paper (provided I did not sign my rights away already) that I turn in?  Is there any thing prohibiting this in copyright law that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 4):

You automatically have copyright protection for what you create. A collection of numeric answers to math equations probably would not qualify (lack of requisite creativity), but certainly anything that counts as a "paper" is protected.